# codeigniter session save to database keep updating many times

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, destructor

I have a question. I'm using latest version of CI.

I have currently enabled session to use the database, but there is only one problem with how it works since it tends to update the database every time you update your session.

**Is there a way to fix that so that session would only update the database once before it destructs?!**

I currently have around 9 update requests from one CI session only :) ! so any help would be lovely.

[image]

a simple Code example, my proccess is much more complicated than this, but just for demonstration purpose

Controller/auth [include post with true login]

```
function login(){
$trial=$this->user->attempt($this->input->post('user'),$this->input->post('pass'));

if($trial){
//1st update query
$this->session->set_userdata('user',$trial);


//Start intializing user

//2nd update query
$this->load->model('relations');//constructer will load user friends and save them to $this->session->set_userdata('relations',$rel);

//3rd update query
$this->load->model('settings');//construtor will load user settings and save them to settings
}
}
```

Above code will create 3 update request all targeted to update field userdata = current session.

my point is there is no need to update db every time we add something to session, its already saved in $_SESSION, so keep it there , and keep manipulating $_SESSION till end,

only updating user_data once at the end of all runtime -destructor- with the end result session is enough to save session to db.

please note that CI loads session from session using `select * from ci_session` (first request in picture) and then it just keep updating session repeatedly and pointless since it will not select it again during runtime !

so why not just LOAD it once session library is loaded. and save it just before it destruct. thats what im trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Comment: Surely if you decide to store your session data in the database, then the database will have to be updated whenever the session is updated? Why would you want it not to update?

Comment: Surely it should update.. BUT only once is enought right !! it doesnt have to update every single time.. how about only once after all work is done ?

Comment: What code in your program is causing these requests?

Comment: Please post the code that updates your session.

Comment: _'my point is there is no need to update db every time we add something to session, its already saved in $_SESSION, so keep it there , and keep manipulating $_SESSION till end,'_ CodeIgniter does **not** use native PHP sessions, so `$_SESSION` is irrelevant - try to `print_r($_SESSION)` to see that it will be empty. The session data is stored in the database, so that's why it has to be updated when you want to update the session data. [Reading the user guide should provide more useful information.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: @lefters if what your saying is true, then CI should also fire a SELECT query after every UPDATE query to update session.. which doesnt not happen, i know that $_SESSION is not used but there must be other variable that is. i didnt know its name so i used $_SESSION.

Comment: Why would it need to fire the `SELECT`? The session data is stored in the database. The only session information stored outside of the database is in a session cookie, which contains a reference to the appropriate row in the session table of the database, **not** the user data.

Comment: @Lefters yp so when i do set_userdata('XXX') it update database to store session and when i call userdata('XXX') it doesn't SELECT anything, may be you are right, nice magic CI. thanks anyway i gave up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this, get the existing user data from the session by using following code

```
$userdata = $this->session->all_userdata();
$userdata['fname'] = 'John';
$userdata['lname'] = 'Mulharn';
$userdata['email'] = 'Mulharn@john.com';
$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
```

All this happens in 1 transaction instead of 3 database transaction. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A session may be updated by passing an array with all of the values, rather than doing them one at a time. Have another look in the Users' Guide

Comment: what does that have to do with anything ?

Comment: I can't tell from your code, but I was guessing you were updating individual values separately. If you don't want to keep updating, find where your updates are occurring & stop doing them. Otherwise, don't use db updates